# Json encode cannot plot using flot

Tags: php, json, flot

I have extreme difficulties finding ways to json encode in flot. Firstly, I send an array of data, for example, `00:00-00:30` from my php to my javascript. However, when I use the alert function to debug, I will see

`({'':"00:00-00:30", 1:"00:30-01:00", 2:"01:00-01:30", 3:"01:30-02:00", 4:"02:00-02:30", 5:"02:30-03:00", 6:"03:00-03:30", 7:"03:30-04:00", 8:"04:00-04:30", 9:"04:30-05:00"...})`

I'm quite lost at the moment at why can't I just send `00:00-00:30` and the rest into json encode without the quotes. Many thanks!

My php array code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name6 WHERE Month = '$test'";   
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $times = $row['Time'];
 $demand = $row['Demand'];

 $arraytime[$countdown] = $times;
 $arraydata[$countdown] = $demand;
 $countdown = $countdown + 1;

 }
```

My javascript code:

```
$(function () {
var graph = [];
var power = <?php echo json_encode($arraydata);?>;
var time = <?php echo json_encode($arraytime);?>;
alert(time.toSource());
```

Comment: Use string instead of array probably.

Comment: do you mean changing my $arraydata[] into a string?

Comment: I need to pass my array into my javascript because I want to process this data in javascript before plotting

Comment: The first time your database fetch loop iterates, $countdown isn't defined and will evaluate to an empty string for the array key. Beyond that, you're creating an array and GETTING an array in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You are pulling values like "00:00-00:30" from your database.  What format is this stored in in the database?  I'm guessing a varchar which is a string.  You pull them out of the database you get a php string and when you json_encode a php string, you get a back a javascript string (hence the enclosed with quotes).  Not very surprising.

Let's start at the end game.  What values do you want to pass to flot?  Are "00:00-00:30", "00:30-01:00", etc... categories for like a pie or bar chart?  Is it the labels you want on your xAxis?

What does "power" look like?  Are these numeric values?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want as an end result, but I'm guessing that you want an array of dates that you can pass to flot.  If that's the case, try initializing $countdown to 0.  It will change this:

```
{"":"00:30-01:00","1":"01:00-01:30","2":"01:30-02:00"}
```

to this:

```
["00:30-01:00","01:00-01:30","01:30-02:00"]
```

From there you can get the actual date object by using the Date() function with the string as an argument.